# No line number specified in console error message. What to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, compiler-errors, console

In a recent day I faced with this kind of error message, that has no position specified. Debugging becomes much more difficult. What did I do wrong?

When I started re-define `JSON.parse` functions of my objects, after that appears it first time.
I replaced them to normal functions, but the error message is still strange.

Maybe because I'm writing prototype functions, and I call them before constructing a new object?

Is it because I call a function from console?

[image: Line number missing]

Comment: undefined part...where is that line?

Comment: well that's the point, I'll explain...

Comment: undefined was nothing special, i thought there was a error, but not

Comment: are you using any jquery??

Comment: have you included multiple js in your files..and mention the code where you have used charCodeAt()?

Comment: i think it is inside of internal function `JSON.parse()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36772/discussion-between-vagabond-and-2astalavista)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to simplify the error:

```
var o = {g : false};
function f(){
    console.log(o.g());
}
```

If I call it from Chrome and form console, than I will not get any line number.